# Index-match function returns #N/A when number is used as text

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I'm using index-match formula for extracting data from a table("DETAIL"). The formula works well when cell B6 contains number in General/Number format but returns to #N/A when cell B6 contains number in text format. I cant convert it as number because it may be started from zero (0) which disappears when number is used as general format. My formula is

```
=INDEX(DETAIL,MATCH(B6,BMID,0),MATCH(D5,DATA_R,0))
```

[image: Highlighted cell (B6) contains number as number]

Comment: in what cell are you using the formula and what is the end result you want?

Comment: Then format the data where you're matching against as text as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
=INDEX(DETAIL,MATCH(Value(B6),BMID,0),MATCH(D5,DATA_R,0))
```

I don't see any harm in converting `B6` to number using `VALUE()`. See image for reference.

[image]